# Slice indexing weird edge case

Tags: go, indexing

In Go slice indices use half-open range.  For a[low:high] the slice includes a[low] but exclude a[high].  Ref: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7.  Another way to think of it is it goes from a[low] to a[high-1] inclusive.

But take a look at this code.  You can run it at: https://play.golang.com/p/DSLs7V8gom0

```
func main() {
    t := []int{5}
    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Println(t[0:0])
    fmt.Println(t[1:1])
}
```

If you ran the code you can see that both t[0:0] and t[1:1] are valid and allowed.

t[0:0] means includes t[0] (which exists) but stop before t[0] (which is t[-1] which does not exist).

t[1:1] means includes t[1] (which does not exist) but stop before t[1] (which is t[0] which exists).

In both cases one of the indices refer to something that doesn't exist, i.e. index out of range ==> yet syntactically perfect and allowed in Golang!!

Yet if you try any other index, such as t[2], the compiler will expectedly complain loudly.

Comment: Your question is not clear. It's allowed because the spec explicitly describes it as a valid expression with specific behaviour https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions

Comment: *"Another way to think of it is it goes from a[low] to a[high-1] inclusive."* That's the wrong way to think about it. As explained in the [link](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7) you've provided: *"`a[low : high]` This selects a half-open range which includes the first element, **but excludes the last one**."* "Excluding" `high` is something very different from "indexing" `high-1`.

Comment: *"t[1:1] means includes t[1] (which does not exist)"*, True `t[1]` does not exits, however `t[1:1]` and `t[1]` are not the same types of expressions, one is a slice expression the other an indexing expression, see the link provided by zerkms. And the pertinent sentence in that spec is this one: *"For slices, the upper index bound **is the slice capacity cap(a) rather than the length**."* See https://play.golang.com/p/29n1_0K4oS0 and https://play.golang.com/p/TTTPeVqGWtr

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, yes it's valid per spec.  I guess what I got hung up on is the way I think about it which mkopriva nicely pointed out and corrected.

Comment: @mkopriva This helped changed the way I view things "Excluding high is something very different from "indexing" high-1".  It's subtle but does explain away the perceived weirdness.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to think of a range as starting at the lower value and stopping when you reach the upper value. The upper can never be less than the lower but they can be any valid index or the one past the end - ie 0 or 1 in your example.

So `t[0:0]` means start then stop immediately giving a zero-length range.  Eg:

`t[0:0]` and `t[1:1]` are valid zero length slices

`t[0:1]` is a slice of length 1

`t[2:2]` and `t[1:0]` are invalid

I explain in detail about the advantages of half-open ranges and not making zero a special case in my blog - eg see http://devmethodologies.blogspot.com/2012/12/asymmetric-bounds-and-zero-based.html

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I guess what I got hung up on is the way I view the half-open range, which @mkopriva nicely pointed out and corrected.  "Excluding high is something very different from "indexing" high-1". It's subtle but does explain away the perceived weirdness.